# TypeError: read_csv() got an unexpected keyword argument ‘sheetname’ when merging csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I’m trying to merge a bunch of csv files using pandas but I am getting the above error from the code below.  Each csv file has one sheet but they are named differently so I am trying to say “I want the first sheet”.  I’ve tried both sheet_names and sheetnames with the same error each time.  Am I missing something?

```
import os
import pandas as pd

#show current working directory and list files
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
files

#pick out csv files
files_csv = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'csv']

#initialize empty data frame
df = pd.DataFrame()

#loops over list of files to append empty dataframe
for f in files_csv:
    data = pd.read_csv(f, sheetname=0, engine='openpyxl')
    df = df.append(data)

df.to_csv('ConsolidatedResults.csv')
```

Comment: your question is a bit confusing, could you please elaborate and provide an example if possible?

Comment: @Sai Pardhu thanks for your response.  I have 100 csv files that I want to combine into one consolidated csv file.  Each csv file has a unique name and the sheet name is the same as the file name for each of the 100 csv files.  I want find the csv files that are in the same directory as my script, loop through them and consolidate.

Comment: if they are csv files im guessing the sheet name shouldn't matter, you can remove that parameter, also as @T C Liu in the answer mentioned, that looks like a parameter for read_excel , not csv

Answer (score 1):

read_csv() have no argument 'sheetname'; read_excel() have one argument 'sheet_name'.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html